# Using Excel 2013 with C# incorrect row numbers

Tags: c#, excel

I have a weird issue in my app. I am copy some data into Excel. I have a int variable called rowCounter which I set to 1. I then export the data from my list in excel using my rowCounter variable (code below). What is strange is that in excel it puts the data into row 10 rather than row 1. If I change the rowCounter to 7 excel will put the data into row 70. Has anyone else had this issue?

When stepping through the code I can see the value of my rowCounter is what I expect.

```
int rowCounter = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < _fundCodes.Count; i++)
{
    // some code - pulling some data from a database nothing to do with the row counter

    for (int m = 0; m < missingAuto.Count; m++)
    {
        _xlWorksheet.Range["B" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingAuto[m].FundCode;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["C" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingAuto[m].IdSedol;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["D" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingAuto[m].Currency;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["E" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingAuto[m].Nominal;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["F" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingAuto[m].Price;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < missingMan.Count; m++)
    {
        _xlWorksheet.Range["H" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingMan[m].FundCode;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["I" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingMan[m].IdSedol;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["J" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingMan[m].Currency;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["K" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingMan[m].Nominal;
        _xlWorksheet.Range["L" + rowCounter + m].Value = missingMan[m].Price;
    }

    int rowAdd = missingAuto.Count > missingMan.Count ? missingAuto.Count : missingMan.Count;

    rowCounter = rowCounter + rowAdd + 2;
}
```

Comment: When you debug, evaluate `"B" + rowCounter + m` and see what cell you're specifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are adding strings instead of numbers:

```
"B" + rowCounter + m
"B" + 1 + 0
"B10"
```

Correct version:

```
"B" + (rowCounter + m).ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

`"B" + rowCounter + m` is the same as `"B" + rowCounter.ToString() + m.ToString()`.
So when rowCounter is 1 and m is 0, you get B10.